# Flink: Using MATCH_RECOGNIZE in a VIEW

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep, flink-sql

I'd like to create a view that contains a `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` statement. This runs into the following error:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException: SQL parse failed. Encountered "MATCH_RECOGNIZE" at line 3, column 79.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF>
    "EXCEPT" ...
    "FETCH" ...
    "GROUP" ...
    "HAVING" ...
    "INTERSECT" ...
    "LIMIT" ...
    "OFFSET" ...
    "ORDER" ...
    "MINUS" ...
    "TABLESAMPLE" ...
    "UNION" ...
    "WHERE" ...
    "WINDOW" ...
    "(" ...
    "NATURAL" ...
    "JOIN" ...
    "INNER" ...
    "LEFT" ...
    "RIGHT" ...
    "FULL" ...
    "CROSS" ...
    "," ...
    "OUTER" ...
```

If you'd like to reproduce this issue, you could e.g. follow the [Ververica training](https://github.com/ververica/sql-training/wiki/Pattern-Matching-with-MATCH_RECOGNIZE) which covers MATCH_RECOGNIZE as well.

After the initial setup, create the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW `RideView`
AS
SELECT rideId, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, startT, endT) AS durationMin
FROM Rides
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY rideId
  ORDER BY rideTime
  MEASURES 
    S.rideTime AS startT, 
    E.rideTime AS endT
  AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
  PATTERN (S E)
  DEFINE
    S AS S.isStart,
    E AS NOT E.isStart
);
```

Just running `SELECT * FROM RideView` will trigger the issue.

This isn't unexpected because the [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html#sql-semantics) says that

> Currently, the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause can only be applied to an append table. Furthermore, it always produces an append table as well. (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html#sql-semantics).

**Is there any way to overcome this limitation and use MATCH_RECOGNIZE in conjunction with `CREATE VIEW AS <query>`?**

Comment: hi Daniel, have you solved this problem? I also encountered this issue.

Comment: @armysheng I'm afraid I didn't. Might be worth to check the Flink roadmap for 1.12 and 1.13 to see if that's on their to-do list though.